# Troubles installing windows 7 on a acer aspire m1641

Tags: windows-7, windows, acer-aspire

I'm having problems with instaling Windows 7 on a acer aspire m1641.

For some reason, the recovery disk isn't ready, because when sellecting the boor options, no D2D is available. (maybe there is a bios setting which I can't find to enable it?) Some bios have a D2D option.

All drives have SATA connectors.

The C drive is formatted, so I can't upgrade to Windows 7, a clean instal is nessesary.

Can anyone tel me what to do next?

This is what I tried this far.

- Boot with windows 7 DVD
- Trying to find a "enable D2D option, nothing found
- Trying to go back to Vista with a vista DVD, problem, no drivers found.

Edit:

I just slip streamed windows 7 with the AHCI/SATA drivers for Vista, Let's see if this works

Comment: Slipstreaming vista with satadrivers went very well too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you be more specific about the problem that causes the Windows 7 installation to fail?

Your comment "no drivers found." leads me to think that Vista/7 doesn't have built in drivers for your SATA controller.  If the option is available in BIOS, change the SATA controller's mode from AHCI to IDE, and try again.

If that is the case, try downloading the SATA drivers from Acer's web site, and put them on a USB drive.  When the Windows installer complains about drivers, put the USB drive in and pull the drivers from there.

Comment: It was a hdd problem, after a good format, everything went well